# Connect to a MySQL database using SSL certificates in using C# .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-code, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to connect to a remote Mysql database using SSL. The implementation is in C# and dotnet core 3. I have written some code but it doesn't seem to be successful. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
using System.Data;

using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public class Tutorial1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection( "database=your_databasename;user=your_username;" + "SslMode=VerifyFull;" + "SslCa=server-ca.pem;" + "SslCert=client-cert.pem;" +"SslKey=client-key.pem;");

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            connection.Open();
            // Perform database operations
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Dev DB");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's show your error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out. Apparently Connector/Net does not work with .pem certificate files because of some bug. So the solution to this is that we need to convert .pem to .pfx like so:

openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem -certfile cacert.pem -out client.pfx

This is where I got this from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl-pfx.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug in Oracle's Connector/NET (aka MySql.Data) when it comes to PEM handling: [bug 95436](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95436).

Try switching to [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/)). It has the same API as Connector/NET, so it should be a drop-in replacement, but has better PEM file handling and better support for .NET Core.